# Add screen of a laptop to another one when both are on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, display

I have two laptops and I want to add screen of another laptop to my laptop. So that I will be having a wider space to see my stuffs I believe there must be some software/technique to meet my requirement.

Comment: Could you be more clear? Do you want to see the contents of your first laptop in the second laptop? or Do you want to extend the display into the second laptop's screen? so that some events happen in 1st screen and some of them in second screen like playing a movie, which plays half of the movie in 1st screen and other half in 2nd screen?

Answer (score 1):

**Not Possible.**
Consumer laptops only have a video out port, never video in. However their is a software [synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) that you can use to share the same keyboard and mouse but it can not make them as a one big screen. So the short answer is no it won't work.